# Rails page load, where to look?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I have this

```
Completed 200 OK in 3503ms (Views: 1203.3ms | ActiveRecord: 75.5ms | Solr: 90.8ms)
```

But sum of three times does not give me 3503ms

Where other place should I look to improve page load time?

Comment: Come one you have views that load for over one sec, that's the first place to look!

Comment: they were loading in 10 secs, anyway there are about 2 seconds in something invisible

Answer (score 1):

Try installing New Relic and using its [developer mode](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/developer-mode) for a more detailed break down of where time is being spent.